# while calling method showing variable undefine in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-controller, action

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:SComponent$controller$arResult [str is not defined] Failing
>   descriptor: {c:SComponent$controller$arResult}

when click on the button whatever text i have entered is showing in alert box which is correct but after alert i am setting parameter from setParams it's throwing error str is not defined.

i have use this in this way :--> action.setParams({str,sear});

and this way -->action.setParams({"str",sear}); and everytime i am getting same error which is mentioned above.

**Apex Controller Code is below**

```
 public class SearchController {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Contact> archCon(String str){
    List<contact> conList = new List<contact>();
    if(Str != null){
         conList = [SELECT id FirstName, LastName, phone FROM CONTACT WHERE FirstName =: str];
    }
    return conList;
 }
}
```

Component code below

```
 <lightning:input type="text" aura:id="input1" label="Enter a text"  />
                <lightning:button  label="Search Record" title="Search" onclick="{!c.arResult }"/>
```

Component controller code is below

```
({
arResult : function(component, event, helper) {
    var sear = component.find("input1").get("v.value");
    alert(sear);
    var action = component.get("c.archCon");

    **action.setParams({str,sear});**

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        if(response.getState()==="SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){

            alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());

        }
    });
       $A.enqueueAction(action); 
   }

})
```

Comment: Use action.setParams({"str" : sear});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should actually need to use JSON syntax to pass params using `action.setParams()` method.

So in your case you need to pass it either like this:

```
action.setParams({str:sear});
```

Or like this:

```
action.setParams({"str":sear});
```